# Seaside - Reporting with submit buttons

Tags: smalltalk, seaside

Is something like the following valid?

```
TransactionReport := WATableReport new
            rows: SpendingManager instance entriesForPosting asArray;
        columns: (OrderedCollection new    
        add: (WAReportColumn 
                    renderBlock: [ :each :html | (html submitButton 
                            callback: [ SpendingManager removeTransaction: each. self renderReport ];
                            text: 'Backout Transaction')]
                    title: '');
```

It does actually render the submit button with each row, but clicking it doesn't appear to do anything.

---

I've been able to kinda of accomplish this, though it's not as pretty as a button:

```
add: (WAReportColumn new 
                title: '';
                valueBlock: [:anEvent | 'delete'];
                clickBlock: [ :each | SpendingManager instance removeTransaction: each]);
            yourself);
```

Would still love some feedback.

Answer (score 3):

Submit Buttons that do nothing are most likely not inside a form tag. So can you check if your report works if you embed it into a html form: [] block?

If a form is not an option, you can replace the submit buttons with anchors. You can use css to make anchors look like buttons if that aspect is important.